# matlab to python fread with eof

Tags: python, matlab, nested, eof, fread

I'm having some trouble implementing the following MATLAB code in python.

```
for i = 1:N
    if (feof(fid) ~= 1)
        for j = 1:K
            if (feof(fid) ~= 1)
                    tmp = fread(fid, 1, 'float');
                    data.(fldnames{j,1}).Samples(i) = tmp;
            else
                disp('Error: End of file reached');
            end
        end
    else
        disp('Error: End of file reached');
    end
```

This is my 'like-for-like' python attempt,

```
sampleList = numpy.zeros((N, K))
for i in range(1, N) :
    for j in range(1, K) : 
        if EOF == 0 :
            try : 
                samples = array.array("f")
                samples.fromfile(f, 1)
                sampleList[i, j] = samples[0]
            except : 
                EOF = 1
return sampleList
```

But I'm having trouble catching both of the EOFs. Is there an easier, more pythonic way of writing this code?

Comment: where does EOF  come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the matlab code does in python:

```
def read_data(filename, fieldnames, n):
    data = numpy.fromfile(filename, count=n * len(fieldnames))
    assert len(data) == n * len(fieldnames)
    return dict((key, data[idx::len(fieldnames)]) for idx, key in enumerate(fieldnames))
```

I assume that the number of field names is `K` and that `fid` is a filehandle to the file `filename`, and that `n` is the number of items per field `N`. What you get is a dictionary with fieldnames, which is equivalent to a struct in matlab.

Comment: That looks great, thanks. Definitely better than just an NxK array.

Comment: Just trying this now, the dictionary this function returns seems to only have 5 elements (len(myDict["data_1"]) == 5. This should definitely return a dict of fieldnames, each one with n elements? What could be causing it to only have 5 elements? Your assumptions are correct.

Comment: look at the length of `data`. If there are not enough numbers in the file, then the `data`-Vector is too short.

Comment: would just like to add I fixed this, data was not long enough as you said, the cause was me not opening the binary file with the extra "rb" argument, so all of the file wasn't being read

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where some of your values are coming from but if you want to catch the Exception:

```
        for j in range(1, K) :
            try :
                samples = array.array("f")
                samples.fromfile(f, 1)
                sampleList[i, j] = samples[0]
            except EOFError: # catch eof exception
                print ('Error: End of file reached')
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know you could catch the EOFError explicitly like that. My EOF was just a flag, I don't think it was doing anything useful, I was trying to break out of the loop if I get EOF. I've since realized that my problem is somewhere else, as I continuously catch the exception when I'm reading the file, which doesn't happen in MATLAB